# Machine Learning and ROS

Tags: control, ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im collecting lots of data from my robot runs and I wonder if possible some implementation of some Machine Learning techniques in ROS. Or if I can use some machine learning techniques like Support Vector Machine Classifier or some other in correlation with ROS? I would like to do like shared control of the Joystick of my platform so I thought Machine Learning is a good approach.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66060/machine-learning-and-ros/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use OpenCV or Matlab with ROS. OpenCV is not so powerful in comparison wit Matlab, but you can find SVM in OpenCV.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-06-27**:
ok.. Any examples or tutorial regarding machine learning with Matlab and ROS??